# Passing field from awk pattern match into shell date command substitution

Tags: bash, shell, date, awk

I would like to convert a (ISO 8601) date from `YYYY-MM-DD` to something that looks like `Mon, 03 Dec 2021 00:00:00 -0600` (RFC-822 / RFC 5322). I have not been able to find questions that address this specific issue.

I have an RSS XML file that looks like this:

```
bash-5.1$ cat feed.xml                                                                                                                                                                                              
<rss version="2.0">                                                                                                                                                                                 
    <channel>                                                                                                                                                               
        <title>Title string</title>                                                                                                                                                                                               
        <link>https://domain/feed.xml</link>                                                                                                                                                                                                
        <description>Description string here</description>                                                                                                                                                    
        <language>en-us</language>                                                                                                                                                                                                             
<item>                                                                                                                                          
<title>title string here</title>                                                                                                                                                                                 
<link>link string with https style information</link>                                                                                                                                                                 
<guid>link string with https style information</guid>                                                                                                                                                                 
<pubDate>2021-12-03</pubDate>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</item>                                                                                                                                             
<item>                                                                                                                                          
<title>title string here</title>                                                                                                                                                                                 
<link>link string with https style information</link>                                                                                                                                                           
<guid>link string with https style information</guid>                                                                                                                                                           
<pubDate>2019-08-13</pubDate>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</item>       
<item>                                                                                                                                          
<title>title string here</title>                                                                                                                                                                                 
<link>link string with https style information</link>                                                                                                                                                           
<guid>link string with https style information</guid>                                                                                                                                                           
<pubDate>2018-11-23</pubDate>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
</item>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
</channel>
</rss>
```

The output I expect after parsing would be something like this:

```
...
<pubDate>Fri, 03 Dec 2021 00:00:00 -0600</pubDate> 
...
<pubDate>Tue, 13 Aug 2019 00:00:00 -0500</pubDate> 
...
<pubDate>Fri, 23 Nov 2018 00:00:00 -0600</pubDate> 
...
```

This output can usually be achieved with the bash `date` command like so:

```
bash-5.1$ date -d "2018-11-23" +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z"
Fri, 23 Nov 2018 00:00:00 -0600
```

I am trying to accomplish this with `awk` because I learned that command substitution is possible, and I believe I am close, but not quite:

```
bash-5.1$ awk -F "[><]" -v date="$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z" -d "$3")" '/pubDate/ {print $3date}' feed.xml 
2021-12-03Sun, 05 Dec 2021 00:00:00 -0600
2019-08-13Sun, 05 Dec 2021 00:00:00 -0600
2018-11-23Sun, 05 Dec 2021 00:00:00 -0600
```

It seems like the pattern match executes successfully as well as the date command, but the awk `$3` field looks like is not being passed into the shell `date` command and so the current time is showing instead of the transformed time.

How do I pass the `$3` field from the awk pattern match into the date command so that it can convert the date based on the field value?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: wrong tool for the task? Why not use an xml parser in python, node.js, or similar?

Comment: Thank you for the quick turnaround. This is part of a larger shell script and so I'm trying to limit dependencies for ease of portability. I would be open to use other shell alternatives if they're better suited than awk though.

Comment: @grokkingnix if portability is a concern, then use a scripting language with native xml support like Python or Perl. Because neither oak, sed or bash is able to reliably parse the complexity of markup languages. It may work for a while and a minor adjustment to the xml structure can break it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, this is one of the last things I will implement for this script so once it's complete I will look into porting all functionality over to python. I should have mentioned that I create the XML file within the script so I have complete control over its structure and can trust that it won't easily change. I do agree that other tools might be better/faster to implement though, so this will be the perfect excuse to learn python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, it is recommended to use xml parsing tool speaking generally.
If the xml file is well aligned as the provided example, `bash` or `awk`
may work under limited conditions.
With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ (.*<pubDate>)([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(</pubDate>.*) ]]; then
        datestr=$(date -d "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
        line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$datestr${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < feed.xml
```

The condition `$line =~ (.*<pubDate>)([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(</pubDate>.*)` matches the `<pubdate>` line assiging bash variable `${BASH_REMATCH[@]` to
the parenthesized substrings. Then `line` is reconstructed using the reformatted date string.

If `gawk` which supports `mktime()` and `strftime()` functions, you can
also say with `gawk`:

```
awk '
{
    if (match($0, /^(.*<pubDate>)([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})(<\/pubDate>.*)/, a) ) {
        ts = mktime(a[2] " " a[3] " " a[4] " 00 00 00")    # timestamp since the epoch
        datestr = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %T %z", ts)
        $0 = a[1] datestr a[5]
    }
} 1' feed.xml
```

Comment: Thank you @tshiono, this creates the expected output. I will look deeper into the way `BASH_REMATCH` works as this is my first encounter with it. I will look into porting this over to python as well so that it's more robust. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. Good to know it works. If you have any questions in further investigation including python implementation, please feel free to ask me or whoever. (You can get in touch with me by commenting here then.) Happy hacking and good luck. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Altering your `awk` code slightly.

```
$ awk -v date="$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=">"}$1~/pubDate/{split($2,a,"<"); a[1]=date; $2=a[1]"<"a[2]}1' input_file
<rss version=2.0>                                                                                                                                                                            
    <channel>
        <title>Title string</title>                                                                                                                                                          
        <link>https://domain/feed.xml</link>                                                                                                                                                 
        <description>Description string here</description>                                                                                                                                   
        <language>en-us</language>                                                                                                                                                           
<item>
<title>title string here</title>                                                                                                                                                             
<link>link string with https style information</link>                                                                                                                                        
<guid>link string with https style information</guid>                                                                                                                                        
<pubDate>Mon, 06 Dec 2021 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>                                                                                                                                           
</item>
<item>
<title>title string here</title>                                                                                                                                                             
<link>link string with https style information</link>                                                                                                                                        
<guid>link string with https style information</guid>                                                                                                                                        
<pubDate>Mon, 06 Dec 2021 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>                                                                                                                                           
</item>
<item>
<title>title string here</title>                                                                                                                                                             
<link>link string with https style information</link>                                                                                                                                        
<guid>link string with https style information</guid>                                                                                                                                        
<pubDate>Mon, 06 Dec 2021 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>                                                                                                                                           
</item>                                                                                                                                                                                      
</channel>
</rss>
```

`sed` can also be used if the variable is set.

```
$ date="$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")" 
$ sed "/pubDate/ s/....-..-../$date/" input_file
```

Comment: Thank you I need to review what the awk command is doing to replace the line like that. The output of your updated awk command seems to be giving the current date instead of transforming the original dates, this seems like a step in the right direction though, now just to update with the transformed dates.